# how do i set a program to run based on file type and not file name

Tags: linux, wine

The end result I require is as follows:
when I run an executable file on linux (from terminal or some gui), it must automatically be run by wine if it is a typical windows binary.
i know how to set a program to run based on a files extention, but is it possible to do it based on type? in  this case the windows format is PE32
Why would I want it this way? so I dont need to type e.g. "wine notepad" for the many commands in various dirs i need to execute

Answer (score 1):

Linux has mechanisms in place to launch executables according to their contents, through the `binfmt_misc` mechanism. Look [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html) for the gory details. Chances are it is already set up for many executable types by your distribution, check in the "directory" `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` what is enabled.